# electrical, additional lights

Tags: lighting

I want to add some lights in my basement.  currently there is two lights with 12gauge wire on 20 amp breaker.

Can I add lights using 14 garage to the chain of existing lights?

Comment: I don't want to edit your question, in case I'm missing something, but do you mean "14 gauge", as opposed to "14 garage"? Also, please note your approximate location, so we can understand what code applies.

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless you also swap the breaker out for a 15A.
If there's 14g anywhere on the circuit you can't use a 20A breaker.